# Simple one-page application with API, how to start

Tags: rest, api, single-page-application

I recently got a simple task to create one-page application with feeds showing from API. It should be possible to add, edit, delete feed. Add/remove like etc.
I spent last few hours trying to figure out how to start. I created several websites using HTML, CSS and some jQuery or Bootstrap.This is new to me.

API is here: http://fe-zadanie.herokuapp.com
Available: GET, PUT, DELETE

I do not want somebody to write code for me. I just need some little nudge on how to start. I found various sources to study but I cannot find something usable to study and to start from.

Any help would be nice, thank you.

Comment: do you want your API to connect with web application?

Comment: or just consume the rest api?

Comment: Yes, to connect. I should get data from API (information about feeds (ID, number of likes etc.) and show these feed in web application. Thank you for answer.

Comment: you can read this article https://www.sitepoint.com/angular-2-tutorial/

Comment: it will give you the basics of designing single page website.